# Smartmontools 7.3 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, ssd, usb-drive, smart

I bought a SSD enclosure equipped with the **Asmedia 2364** chipset.

Ubuntu 22.04 is shipped with Smartmontools 7.2 that does not support that chipset. Instead, the 7.3 can address it by the switch `-d sntasmedia`.

For testing I built it from sources, but I would rely on the stock Ubuntu packages.

Ubuntu 23 ships the 7.3, so I would ask you if it is possibile to install it, or when the backport will be available for the 22.04

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Thank you, it may answer. Do you know where I could download the packages shipped for the 23.04 in order to test it on a virtual machine?

Comment: If it was available for a *year* product (eg. Ubuntu Core 22 is the *year* flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server) then it'll run on all releases as *year* products are *snap* only, and *snap* packages run on all, alas there is no Ubuntu 23 as *year* products are released only on the *even* years (ie. Ubuntu Core 22 was released; next will be Ubuntu Core 24 a few months after Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server is released)

Comment: All Ubuntu builds are done on launchpad; eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/smartmontools will provide details for the *lunar* or 23.04 system, or you could follow links at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=smartmontools&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all for any release...  This also allows you to get source, or built packages depending on what links you follow...

Comment: It is installable.  `smartctl -V
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-72-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org`

Comment: How can I install it on the 22.04?!

Comment: It worked thank you. I want you can write a regular answer to accept as solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a few notes for this solution:

- When you download and install a package manually, you get no updates for it. You have to manually update to a later version of the package.
- And you have to check yourself if the dependencies for the package are satisfied for the newer package on your release.
- And please do not forget to remove the package before a release
  upgrade.

Go to [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), and search for the package you need there:

[image: smartmontools for kinetic]

In this case, you need `smartmontools` for Kinetic, and this can be downloaded from any of the mirrors listed.

Copy one hyperlink and then download the package with `wget` (here listed for http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/smartmontools/smartmontools_7.3-1_amd64.deb):

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/smartmontools/smartmontools_7.3-1_amd64.deb
```

And finally you can install the downloaded deb with `apt` or `dpkg`:

```
sudo apt install ./smartmontools_7.3-1_amd64.deb
```